# Why Are There Horizontal Scrollbars on My Responsive Webpage

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

My website behaves responsively, so **why are there horizontal scroll-bars**? I am confused by this! What does it take for the horizontal scrollbars to disappear? Also, the **header doesn't shrink at the 320px mark** on mobile devices, even though it does it when tested in the code editor....???

Here is the link to my CodePen: https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/Xevyqq

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
  <title></title>
  <head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head>
  <body>
    <div class="Main">
        <div class="Header Box">
          <div id="One"> 
            <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/5ape0obb0f/Ethersonic_Header_Test_a.jpg" width="1000" height="166"/>
          </div>      
        </div>

        <div class = "Second Row">
          <div class="About Us">
          <h1>Technology you can trust</h1>

  <p>Ethersonic Technologies has been servicing Chicago and the surrounding suburbs since April 2008. We are a Certified (VOSB) Veteran Owned Small Business with the Federal Government and a member of the BB​B (Better Business Bureau) with an A+ rating.</p>

  <p>Ethersonic specializes in Computer  diagnosis and repair, Security Camera Installation and repair and Network Installation and Repair</p>
        </div>
        <div class="BBB VOSB">
          <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/284vrnvfsv/BBB_and_VOSB_Logos.jpg" width="200" height="124"/>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="Third Row">
          <div id="Computers">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/1dv3jss5yn/asus-reveals-the-rog-g11-gaming-desktop-491165-2.jpg" width="300" height="203"/>
            <p>
              Desktop and Laptop Repair
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="Security">
          <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/8j0ejlsp7j/Security_Cameras.jpg
" width="300" height="201"/>
            <p>
             Security Camera Systems | <br>
Access Controls Systems |
Intercom Systems 
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="Networking">
          <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/7ymhfqjm3z/Networking_2.jpg" width="300" height="220"/>
            <p>
             Network Installation |
Low Voltage Cabling 
            </p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Fourth Row">
        <div class="container">
          <div id="slider">
      <figure>
 <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/7uayt1hjf3/378c87079dddbfe1d78c9f892695626fl-m0xd-w1020_h770_q80.jpg"/>
<img src="https://s1.postimg.org/11px6krrfz/extralarge.jpg"/>
<img src="https://s1.postimg.org/6yehdl959r/gen_Mid.09186160_1.jpg"/>
<img src="https://s1.postimg.org/8tr267l5fz/ISaly9e2xn0r8r1000000000.jpg"/>
<img src="https://s1.postimg.org/11px6krz5r/ISinl3p5sts48e1000000000_1.jpg"/>
</figure>        
      </div>
        </div>
        <div>
      <div class ="Slideshow Description">
        <p>
          We are Installation Experts! <br>
Offering Customized Installation for Both Residentials and Commercial Properties
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
      <div class="Footer">
         <div>
 © Ethersonic Technologies LLC. All rights reserved.
        </div
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS code:

```
.Main{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1/1r;
  /*background-color: green;*/
  margin: 5px 125px 0 75px;
  grid-gap: 25px;
} 


.Header.Box {
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  /*background-color: red;*/
  grid-gap: 15px;
}



.About.Us{
  font-size: 15px
}

.BBB.VOSB{
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#One, #Two, #Three {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;  
}

.Second.Row{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.Third.Row{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  /*background-color: green;*/
}

#Computers, #Security, #Networking{
   /*border-style: solid;*/
    border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;

}


.Fourth.Row{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 25px;
  /*background-color: blue;*/
}

.container{
  max-width: 500px; 
  /*background-color: blue;*/

}

@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}


.Slideshow.Description{
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.Footer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;  
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  /*background-color: yellow;*/
}



 @media (min-width: 500px){
.Header.Box{ 
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    } 
}

  #One img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;    
  }


@media (min-width: 500px) {
.Second.Row{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
h1{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  font-size: h2;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
#One img{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  }

}


@media (min-width: 500px) {
.Third.Row{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
.Fourth.Row{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems that are causing this.

The first problem is one of [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). You you have a lot of hard-coded `widths` in your imagery (such as `<img src="https://s1.postimg.org/5ape0obb0f/Ethersonic_Header_Test_a.jpg" width="1000" height="166" />`). That's a hard-coded width of `1000px`; far more than a media query of `320px` can handle. Instead, I recommend using a **percentage-based** width, such as `100%`.

Also note that while a media query would indeed add greater specificity than a regular CSS selector (and thus override it), an **inline** `width` attribute like this takes the highest possible level of specificity.

You **can** override this by adding `!important` to your media query `width` declarations, but I'd strongly suggest removing your fixed widths in your images instead, and using new CSS selectors to target the images.

The second problem is your hard-coded `margin` attribute on `.Main`, which adds a margin of `75px` on the left, and `125px` on the right. Sure, that might work for large screens, but on a device with only `320px` in total, you're rendering almost two thirds of your width essentially useless. You should significantly reduce these margins, or alternatively, use **[percentage-based values](http://mattsnider.com/css-using-percent-for-margin-and-padding/)** so they'll adapt.

Also note that `320px` is **far** too small for a standard mobile media query; pretty much the only phones you'll be hitting are old Blackberries. I'd strongly recommend checking out CSS Tricks for **[a list of media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)** for standard devices. The standard for most tablets is `768px`, and the standard for most phones is `576px`.

Here's an updated snippet, with all of the hard-coded `width` and `height` attributes removed, and a simple `img` declaration added to ensure that they don't escape the bounds of their parent:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1/1r;
  /*background-color: green;*/
  margin: 5px 125px 0 75px;
  grid-gap: 25px;
}

.Header.Box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  /*background-color: red;*/
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.About.Us {
  font-size: 15px
}

.BBB.VOSB {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#One,
#Two,
#Three {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.Second.Row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.Third.Row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  /*background-color: green;*/
}

#Computers,
#Security,
#Networking {
  /*border-style: solid;*/
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Fourth.Row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 25px;
  /*background-color: blue;*/
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  /*background-color: blue;*/
}

@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

div#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite;
}

.Slideshow.Description {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.Footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  /*background-color: yellow;*/
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .Header.Box {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

#One img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .Second.Row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  h1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    font-size: h2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  #One img {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .Third.Row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .Fourth.Row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<title></title>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Main">
    <div class="Header Box">
      <div id="One">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/5ape0obb0f/Ethersonic_Header_Test_a.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Second Row">
      <div class="About Us">
        <h1>Technology you can trust</h1>

        <p>Ethersonic Technologies has been servicing Chicago and the surrounding suburbs since April 2008. We are a Certified (VOSB) Veteran Owned Small Business with the Federal Government and a member of the BB​B (Better Business Bureau) with an A+ rating.</p>

        <p>Ethersonic specializes in Computer diagnosis and repair, Security Camera Installation and repair and Network Installation and Repair</p>
      </div>
      <div class="BBB VOSB">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/284vrnvfsv/BBB_and_VOSB_Logos.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Third Row">
      <div id="Computers">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/1dv3jss5yn/asus-reveals-the-rog-g11-gaming-desktop-491165-2.jpg" />
        <p>
          Desktop and Laptop Repair
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="Security">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/8j0ejlsp7j/Security_Cameras.jpg
" />
        <p>
          Security Camera Systems | <br> Access Controls Systems | Intercom Systems
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="Networking">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/7ymhfqjm3z/Networking_2.jpg" />
        <p>
          Network Installation | Low Voltage Cabling
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Fourth Row">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="slider">
          <figure>
            <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/7uayt1hjf3/378c87079dddbfe1d78c9f892695626fl-m0xd-w1020_h770_q80.jpg" />
            <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/11px6krrfz/extralarge.jpg" />
            <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/6yehdl959r/gen_Mid.09186160_1.jpg" />
            <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/8tr267l5fz/ISaly9e2xn0r8r1000000000.jpg" />
            <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/11px6krz5r/ISinl3p5sts48e1000000000_1.jpg" />
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="Slideshow Description">
          <p>
            We are Installation Experts! <br> Offering Customized Installation for Both Residentials and Commercial Properties
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Footer">
      <div>
        © Ethersonic Technologies LLC. All rights reserved.
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thankyou so much for this help! Genius! I'm about to try this out! Also, I used the mobile emulator at Screenfly.com and the smartphone sizes begin at 320px and up, from the Blackberry 8300, to the iphone 3/4 and the Samsung Galaxy S2. I even tested one developer's website and it was beautifully responsive on the Motorola Razr, which is 176px by 220px! I was JEALOUS to high heaven! LOL