# My JavaScript Code For My Calculator Web App is Not Validating in CodePen?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Hi when I put the following JavaScript code into the JS file in my CodePen for my Calculator Web App, it is not validating! First, it says, **"Unexpected token `;`"**, and then when I remove all the semi-colons, it then asks to remove, `**flag**`. Is there something wrong with the CodePen validator? Or is it the JavaScript code? Why wouldn't the semicolons be valid? Aren't those an integral part of JavaScript syntax?

Here is the link to my CodePen:https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/zEBoOQ

Here is my HTML code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ziontific Calculator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1 id="heading">ZIONTIFIC CALCULATOR</h1>
        <div class="form holder">
           <form id="formone" name="calc">
          <input id="display" type="text" name="display" value=".....Get on board...." disabled contenteditable="false" >
          <br>
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="1" onClick=”calc.display.value+=1”>
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="2" onClick="calc.display.value+=2">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="3" onClick="calc.display.value+=3">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="C" onClick="Resetfunction(this.form)">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="<-" onClick="backspace(this.form)">
          <input class="button three" type="button" value="=" onClick="evaluation(this.form)">

          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="4" onClick="calc.display.value+=4">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="5" onClick="calc.display.value+=5">
          <input class="button number one" type="button" value="6" onClick="calc.display.value+=6">
          <input class="button opps one" type="button" value="-" onClick="calc.display.value+='-'">
          <input class="button opps one" type="button" value="%" onClick="calc.display.value+='%'">
          <input class="button end one" type="button" value="cos" onClick="cos_function()">



          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="7" onClick=”calc.display.value+=7”>
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="8" onClick=”calc.display.value+=8”>
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="9" onClick=”calc.display.value+=9”>
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="*" onClick="calc.display.value+='*'">
          <input class="button n" type="button" value="n!" onClick="fact_function()">
          <input class="button sin"type="button" value="sin" onClick="sin_function()">

          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="." onClick="calc.display.value+='.'">
          <input class="button number two" type="button" value="0" onClick="calc.display.value+=0">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="," onClick="calc.display.value+=','">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="+" onClick="calc.display.value+='+'">
          <input class="button opps two" type="button" value="/" onClick="calc.display.value+='/'">
          <input class="button end two" type="button" value="tan" onClick=”tan_function()”>

          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="E" onClick="calc.display.value+=2.718">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="pi" onClick="calc.display.value+=3.141">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="x^y" onClick="power_function()">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="(" onClick="openpara(this.value)">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value=")" onClick="closepara(this.value)">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log" onClick="log_function()">

          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="sqrt" onClick="sqrt_function()">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="LN2" onClick="calc.display.value+=0.693">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="LN10" onClick="calc.display.value+=2.302">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log2E" onClick="calc.display.value+=1.442">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="log10E" onClick="calc.display.value+=0.434">
          <input class="button third row" type="button" value="EXP" onClick="exp_function">

          </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
flag = 0;
function openpara(val)
{
calc.display.value+=val;
flag+=1;
}
function closepara(valval)
{
calc.display.value+=valval;
flag-=1;
}
function backspace(calc)
{
var size = calc.display.value.length;
calc.display.value=calc.display.value.substring(0,size-1);
}
function Resetfunction(calc)
{
calc.display.value=” “;

flag=0;
}
function cos_function()
{
flag+=1;
calc.display.value+=’Math.cos(‘;
}
function sin_function()
{
flag+=1;
calc.display.value+=’Math.sin(‘;
}
function tan_function()
{
flag+=1;
calc.display.value+=’Math.tan(‘;
}
function log_function()
{
flag+=1;
calc.display.value+=’Math.log(‘;
}
function sqrt_function()
{
flag+=1;
calc.display.value+=’Math.sqrt(‘;
}
function exp_function()
{
flag+=1;
calc.display.value+=’Math.exp(‘;
}
function fact(x)
{
factvar=1;
for (i=1;i<=x;i++)
{
factvar=factvar*i;
}
return factvar;
}
function fact_function(x)
{
flag+=1;
calc.display.value+=’fact(‘;
}
function power_function(x)
{
flag+=1;
calc.display.value+=’Math.pow(x,y’;
}
function evaluation(calc)
{
n = calc.display.value;
var size = calc.display.value.length;
var lastchar = calc.display.value.charAt(size)
if(isNaN(lastchar) && lastchar!=”)” && lastchar!=”!”)   {calc.display.value=”syntax error”;}
else if(flag!=0){calc.display.value=”error:paranthesis”;}
else {
result=eval(n);
calc.display.value=result;}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Your CodePen doesn't complain about any syntax errors. Also, did I resolve your [**last question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47084311/why-are-there-horizontal-scrollbars-on-my-responsive-webpage)?

Comment: looks like it has a problem with the encoding of your single and double quotation marks. fix those and the errors begin to disappear.

Comment: @AnthonyRivas, I'm going to try that right now!

Comment: @AnthonyRivas, you were right...and I just have to add some closing brackets to some that I left hanging open lol! Thanks for your help! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Obsidian Age, yes CodePen was showing a warning symbol consisting of a red dot with an exclamation mark within it, and when I clicked on that, it then showed "Unexpected token ;" (highlighted in red). And I'm working on multiple projects. As I soon as a get back to my other web page code, tonight, and work on it, I'll let you know if it works and then put a checkmark besides your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using strangely encoded tick marks. If you update them to the standard it seems to validate fine.

```
flag = 0;

function openpara(val) {
    calc.display.value += val;
    flag += 1;
}

function closepara(valval) {
    calc.display.value += valval;
    flag -= 1;
}

function backspace(calc) {
    var size = calc.display.value.length;
    calc.display.value = calc.display.value.substring(0, size - 1);
}

function Resetfunction(calc) {
    calc.display.value = "";

    flag = 0;
}

function cos_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += 'Math.cos(';
}

function sin_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += 'Math.sin(';
}

function tan_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += 'Math.tan(';
}

function log_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += 'Math.log(';
}

function sqrt_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += 'Math.sqrt(';
}

function exp_function() {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += 'Math.exp(';
}

function fact(x) {
    factvar = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        factvar = factvar * i;
    }
    return factvar;
}

function fact_function(x) {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += 'fact(';
}

function power_function(x) {
    flag += 1;
    calc.display.value += 'Math.pow(x,y';
}

function evaluation(calc) {
    n = calc.display.value;
    var size = calc.display.value.length;
    var lastchar = calc.display.value.charAt(size)
    if (isNaN(lastchar) && lastchar != ")" && lastchar != "!") {
        calc.display.value = "syntax error";
    } else if (flag != 0) {
        calc.display.value = "error:paranthesis";
    } else {
        result = eval(n);
        calc.display.value = result;
    }
}
```